# How to verify the data exists in my db sqlite

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm building an app in phonegap and trying to validate my condition if the 'username'(example) exists in my database local storage, but i have no success.

```
if(getUser(document.getElementById('username').value)){
...
} else{
...//always keeping going here
}

function getUser(username) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        try {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM user where username = ?', [username], function(tx, results) {
            if(results.rows.length > 0) {
            return true);
                } else { return false; }
            });
        } catch(e){}
    });
}
```

Comment: Came in from the SQLite tag. Javascript isn't my forte, but your curly braces and parens don't appear to be balanced. Does this compile and run without errors?

Comment: Yes. It gives that username hasnt been found, as i said, it was example. the real one have tons of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget: executeSql is an asynchronous request. 
Means your function getUser comes to end before getting a result from your query. 
And you have no return value, so your function is return false

```
<script>
function test() {}

if (test())
   console.log('true');
else  
   console.log('false')
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give me the suggestion/advice to validate/verify if the user exists in database?

Comment: didn't try it yet, but you take a look at this post:http://stackoverflow.com/a/12060506/1083906